# Does it matter if British or American English is used?

Tags: discussion, editing

Once someone edited my post due to changing British to American English, e.g. 'memorise' to 'memorize'. Does it really matter?

*I am not criticisng that it is wrong, just curious if American language is default or something.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This topic comes up now and then on different sites, and I always refer to this Meta Stack Exchange question: [What should the standard spelling be - British or US?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23869/295232)
The highest scoring answer by @devinb says:

> At the risk of starting torrents of angry comments, I'd say the correct one is whichever one the OP uses. It is acceptable to fix spelling and grammar errors in someone's response, but if you feel that their favourite spelling of 'behaviour' colours your judgment, then I'm afraid they should just get over it.
>
> **It is not acceptable to change American to British spellings or British to American.**

so about the edit you mention: feel free to roll that part back.

Comment: Yes. Both are acceptable.  (+1)